# docker compose error on startup nodejs app

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to dockerize my nodejs app for both production and development. However this is in its early stages and i need to have different docker files for each environment. 
However, this is currently failing to start in development. Has anybody any solution to fix this?

here is the big picture of the directories:

```
nodejs-app
|-- node_modules
|-- src
|   |-- models
|   `-- index.js
|-- .babelrc
|-- .dockerignore
|-- .gitignore
|-- docker-compose.yml
|-- Dockerfile
|-- package.json
|-- package-lock.json
```

here is the `Dockerfile` content:

```
FROM node:12.7.0-alpine as builder

RUN mkdir -p /code
WORKDIR /code

COPY package.json /code/package.json
COPY package-lock.json /code/package-lock.json

COPY ./src /code

RUN npm install -g nodemon
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000

CMD npm start
```

and here is the `docker-compose.yml` content:

```
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    build: .
    command: npm start
    volumes:
      - "./src:/code"
    ports:
      - "4500:4500"
    networks:
      - apinet

networks:
  apinet:
    driver: bridge
```

and here is the package.json content

```
{
  "name": "nodejs-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node src/index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/node": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-server-express": "^2.8.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "graphql": "^14.4.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.6.8"
  }
}
```

and here is the error i am getting:

```
Creating network "nodejs-app_apinet" with driver "bridge"
Creating nodejs-app_api_1 ... done
Attaching to nodejs-app_api_1
api_1  | npm ERR! path /code/package.json
api_1  | npm ERR! code ENOENT
api_1  | npm ERR! errno -2
api_1  | npm ERR! syscall open
api_1  | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/code/package.json'
api_1  | npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
api_1  | npm ERR! enoent
api_1  |
api_1  | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
api_1  | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-08-04T17_53_47_770Z-debug.log
nodejs-app_api_1 exited with code 254
```

Comment: make sure that file `/code/package.json` exists. Run `docker run -it --rm image-name sh` you will enter into shell and now run ls /code to check if the file exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overwrite the `/code` directory inside the container with the `./src` directory from host file system when mounting the volume in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
volumes:
  - "./src:/code"
```

`./src` directory does not contain `package.json` file, that's why the error happens.

Try to mount the root project directory instead:

```
volumes:
  - ".:/code"
```